# I cannot reset my account psw

Tags: password, reset, administrator

I have a problem I cannot solve. When I first got Ubuntu on my pc, it came with a password I didn’t set and that prevents me from doing basically anything. I tried changing it with all the methods I could find on the internet (sudo passwd root, passwd, selecting “root” from the menu at the beginning, etc) but none of the worked because every  time I try using a sudo command, it asks for a password (which I do not know).
Can anyone help please?

Comment: You really tried ALL the answers in [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) If so, then contact whomever you purchased the PC from, and let them know about your problem.

Comment: Yes, I tried but I cannot go through with any of the solutions proposed because every time it asked for a password to continue. I also tried contacting the shop I bought it from but he said he didn’t set up any password...thanks anyway..

Comment: @ST I can guarantee you that https://askubuntu.com/a/165248/10616 works to force access to reset passwords.  If there is a password on boot *before* getting to the GRUB prompt (press and hold SHIFT at bootup to make it drop to the GRUB prompt and then edit the boot line accordingly), then that's not an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: I tried that...I select "recovery mode" first, then "root" and that's where it asks for a password..I'll try again just in case and I'll get back to you. Thank you!